# tool to extract strings for localization of iPhone/iPad app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, localization, internationalization

Is there a tool that will extract strings from my source code, and replace them with constant names so that I can auto-generate the strings file I need to translate?

Or do I need to search my project for @" and evaluate each string to see if it should be localized, and then move it by hand to a strings.h file?

Comment: i guess no such tool exists. but you can manually do the thing by replacing all entities with constant plus this is confirmed for a single file. not for whole project in a single turn

Answer (score 0):

I have read about two tools to help localization:

- ibtool, to deal with xib files
- genstrings to generate a strings table

As far as I know, both are included in Mac OSX, but I didn't use any of them.